# My custom Save button does not save the new form values

Tags: 7, forms

I added a custom button to my form which I want to call a function which grabs some values from that form, email them out to whomever, and then save the form. I have successfully emailing the value, but I cannot get the form to save.

```
function my_mod_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {


    $type = $form['type']['#value'];
    if($type !== 'support_ticket')
        return;

    $form['actions']['submit2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit', 
        '#value' => t('Accept And Close'),
        '#submit'=>array('my_mod_email_and_close')
    );
    return $form;
}
```

`function my_mod_email_and_close(&$form, &$form_state)` does not contain any logic to actually save the form values. It only checks the form for some values and emails those values out.

I need to save the form however, how do I also get this custom button to submit and save the form. I tried adding these lines to the bottom of `my_mod_email_and_close()`

```
$form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
drupal_form_submit($form_id, $form_state);
```

but it doesn't actually save. I get 2 of the same errrors however: `Trying to get property of non-object in _support_assigned()` from a different module so I am not sure whats going on.

Perhaps I am using the wrong hook?

Comment: Where are you trying to save these values?

Comment: And what errors did you get?

Comment: I edited my post to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the original form's submit function to your #submit array in addition to your custom function.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property

Comment: perfect, thanks! Also - the hook to call in my custom #submit value is 'node_form_submit'